# Detect if face is within a circle

Tags: swift, detection, face-detection, apple-vision

Currently I am working on face detection app. I have implemented face detection part using Apple's Vision.

And app has custom white circle drawn over the screen (you can see in below image).
[image]

Now, how can I detect if face is within that custom white circle or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also done similar project for fun. Link here: https://github.com/sawin0/FaceDetection

For those who don't want to dive into repo.

I have quick suggestion for you, if you have path of circle and face as [CGPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpath) then you can compare circle's and face's bounding box using [`contains(_:using:transform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpath/2427117-contains) .

Here is a code snippet

```
    let circleBox = circleCGPath.boundingBox
    let faceBox = faceRectanglePath.boundingBox
    
    if(circleBox.contains(faceBox)){
        print("face is inside the circle")
    }else{
        print("face is outside the circle")
    }
```

I hope this helps you and others too.

P.S. If there is any better way to do this then please feel free to share.